# How to group by rank and start a new ranking if the difference in months is more than 1 in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to count how long a user has been in a particular group. I'm using rank from `pandas` for this and it works for the most part. But if a user goes back to his previous group is keeps counting instead of starting at new.

Example:

```
#The data
data = {'User_id':[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3],
       'Group':[1,1,2,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,2,2,1,1],
       'Date':['23-01-01','23-02-01','23-03-01','23-04-01','23-05-01',
               '23-01-01','23-02-01','23-03-01','23-04-01','23-05-01',
               '23-01-01','23-02-01','23-03-01','23-04-01','23-05-01']}

df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

df["Months_in_group"] = df.groupby(by=['Group','User_id'])['Date'].transform(lambda x: x.rank(method = 'max'))
```

This is the Result with the code above:

```
#The Result
Result_data = {'User_id':[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3],
        'Group':[1,1,2,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,2,2,1,1],
        'Date':['23-01-01','23-02-01','23-03-01','23-04-01','23-05-01',
               '23-01-01','23-02-01','23-03-01','23-04-01','23-05-01',
               '23-01-01','23-02-01','23-03-01','23-04-01','23-05-01'],
        'Months_in_group': [1,2,1,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,1,1,2,1,2]}
```

And this is what I'm looking for:

```
#the Expected Result
Expected_data = {'User_id':[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3],
        'Group':[1,1,2,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,2,2,1,1],
        'Date':['23-01-01','23-02-01','23-03-01','23-04-01','23-05-01',
               '23-01-01','23-02-01','23-03-01','23-04-01','23-05-01',
               '23-01-01','23-02-01','23-03-01','23-04-01','23-05-01'],
        'Months_in_group': [1,2,1,1,2,1,2,3,4,5,1,1,2,1,2]}`
```

What can I do to start the rank a new?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a shifted helper series and `cumcount`:

```
s = df['Group'].astype(str) + '_' + df['User_id'].astype(str)

df["Months_in_group"] = df.groupby(s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum())[
    'Date'].cumcount().add(1)

print(df)

    User_id  Group      Date  Months_in_group
0         1      1  23-01-01                1
1         1      1  23-02-01                2
2         1      2  23-03-01                1
3         1      1  23-04-01                1
4         1      1  23-05-01                2
5         2      2  23-01-01                1
6         2      2  23-02-01                2
7         2      2  23-03-01                3
8         2      2  23-04-01                4
9         2      2  23-05-01                5
10        3      3  23-01-01                1
11        3      2  23-02-01                1
12        3      2  23-03-01                2
13        3      1  23-04-01                1
14        3      1  23-05-01                2
```

Comment: I would like to at for everybody that uses this to order make sure the order is correct.

df = df.sort_values(by=['User_id', 'Date']).